# Splitting strings within a list by commas while respecting parentheses

Tags: python, string, list, split

I have a list such as

```
a = ['john(is,great),paul,school', 'robert,jack,john']
```

then I am building an empty list to append the split

```
b = []
```

then I do this

```
for i in a:
    b.append(i.split(','))
```

but list be is appearing like this

```
[['john(is', 'great)', 'paul', 'school'], ['robert', 'jack', 'john']]
```

It's doing this because it's splitting at the comma but is there another way to split this so that the output would be

```
['john(is,great)', 'paul', 'school', 'robert', 'jack', 'john']
```

Comment: You have **two** questions here; please keep it to one issue at a time please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `list.extend()` to add elements individually:

```
for i in a:
    b.extend(i.split(','))
```

To split text on commas *not inside parenthesis* you could use the following regular expression:

```
re.split(r',(?=[^()]*(?:\(|$))', i)
```

This splits on a comma only if it is not followed by text containing any parentheses (opening or closing) until the next opening parenthesis. This expression falls down when you have nested parenthesis, but works for your simple case:

```
>>> import re
>>> i = 'john(is,great),paul,school'
>>> re.split(r',+(?=[^()]*(?:\(|$))', i)
['john(is,great)', 'paul', 'school']
```

For more complex splits, use a full-blown parser.

Comment: yea but its still splitting it at the comma  so the first item is in the list which is john(is,great) is returning as 2 strings and not 1 string

Comment: @user3527972: As I said, you have 2 separate questions. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like regular expressions, you could also create a procedure:

```
def splitter(s):
    """Splits a string s on commas, but only if the comma
    is not surrounded by parentheses."""
    if '(' in s and ')' in s:
        start = s.find('(')
        end = s.find(')')
        new = s[start:end].replace(",", "@#$")
        s = s[:start] + new + s[end:]
        return [x.replace("@#$", ",") for x in s.split(",")]
    return s.split(',')

example = ['john(is,great),paul,school','robert,jack,john']

result = list()

for i in example:
    result.append(splitter(i))

print result
# [['john(is,great)', 'paul', 'school'], ['robert', 'jack', 'john']]
```